# not able to get node value in the xpath by getNodeValue function in groovy

Tags: xpath, groovy, soapui

I am not not able to get node value for "idNumber" in the below response xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <SOAP_Customer_Metadata_CALLResponse xmlns="http://BCE/Customer_Metadata_WS.tws">
         <oMetaDataID>
            <ocrStatus>Failed</ocrStatus>
            <guid>123456</guid>
            <docType>03</docType>
            <docDescription>South African ID</docDescription>
            <surname>Choudhary</surname>
            <fullName>Kanika</fullName>
            <idNumber>KANJANDHS293</idNumber>
            <dateOfBirth>22091945</dateOfBirth>
            <dateIssued>01012016</dateIssued>
            <countryOfBirth>India</countryOfBirth>
            <idType>ID</idType>
            <gender>F</gender>
         </oMetaDataID>
         <oMetaDataPOA>
            <ocrStatus>Passed</ocrStatus>
            <surname>Choudhary</surname>
            <idNo>12345</idNo>
            <address1>abc def</address1>
         </oMetaDataPOA>
         <oResubmission>No</oResubmission>
         <oCASASequenceNo>1234578</oCASASequenceNo>
         <oTypeOfCustomer>New</oTypeOfCustomer>
      </SOAP_Customer_Metadata_CALLResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Using the follow code in a *Groovy script* testStep:

```
holder.getNodeValue("//idNumber")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @har07 answers you can define a namespace prefix and then use it in your *XPath*. However *SOAPUI* [`XmlHolder`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/xmlholder.html) supports wildcard `*` for namespaces so you can simply use it on your *XPath*:

```
holder.getNodeValue("//*:idNumber")
```

**EDIT**

The problem using `holder.getNodeValue("//*:oMetaDataID/ocrStatus")` as you do in the comment is that you're missing the namespace for the second element, here you can also use `*` wildcard again as:

```
holder.getNodeValue("//*:oMetaDataID/*:ocrStatus")
```

Comment: Thank you @albciff. this one worked fine. bur when i tried to access "ocrStatus" under "oMetaDataID" tag by using holder.getNodeValue("//*:oMetaDataID/ocrStatus") , I didnt get anything. Please help

Answer (score 1):

That's likely because the XML has *default namespace* :

```
xmlns="http://BCE/Customer_Metadata_WS.tws"
```

All element without prefix within `SOAP_Customer_Metadata_CALLResponse`, including `idNumber`, are considered in that namespace. To select element in default namespace, you need to map a prefix to the default namespace URI, and use that prefix in the XPath. For example, if the registered prefix is `d`: `//d:idNumber` (I don't know groovy but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19672934/2998271) might be useful).

An equivalent, pure-XPath, way would be using combination of XPath functions `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` :

```
//*[local-name()='idNumber' and namespace-uri()='http://BCE/Customer_Metadata_WS.tws']
```